# HTML/Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating the classic fortune teller game in html/javascript. General idea:

Screen A:
1,2,3,4 // click a number and get screen B (2/4)or C(1/3)

Screen B:
5,6,7,8// click a number and get screen B (6/8)or C(5/7)

Screen C:
9,10,11,12// click a number and get screen B (10/12)or C(9/11)

Screen D:
//has fortune on screen

A typical game (based on numbers clicked) would go:

Screen A: Click 2 go to screen B

Screen B: Click 6 go to screen B

Screen B: Click 8 go to screen D

Screen D: fortune

or

Screen A: Click 1 go to screen C

Screen B: Click 10 go to screen B

Screen B: Click 5 go to screen D

Screen D: fortune

I have all the visuals figured out, but I am having a hard time getting the functions to work. My logic makes sense, but I'm having a hard time coding it. If someone could look at it and give me some guidance or suggestions, that would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

            .Square
            {
            width:150px;
            height: 150px;
            text-align:center;
            font-size: 50pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Verdana;
            }
 table { border-collapse: collapse; }


    </style>

<script>


        function startGame()
        {
           document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "1";
           document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "2";
           document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "3";
           document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "4";

        }

        function levelA()
        {
            if(s2||s4)
              {
                  levelB();
                  if(s1||s3)
                   {
                      levelC();
                      if(s1||s2||s3||s4)
                       {
                         levelD();
                       }
                   }
                 if(s2||s4)
                  {
                    levelB();
                      if(s1||s2||s3||s4)
                       {
                         levelD();
                       }
                  }
              }
         else if(s1||s3)
               {
                   levelC();
                  if(s1||s3)
                   {
                      levelC();
                      if(s1||s2||s3||s4)
                       {
                         levelD();
                       }
                   }
                 else if(s2||s4)
                  {
                    levelB();
                      if(s1||s2||s3||s4)
                       {
                         levelD();
                       }
                  }
               }
        }


        function levelB()
        {   
           document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "5";
           document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "6";
           document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "7";
           document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "8";
        }

        function levelC()
        {
           document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "9";
           document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "10";
           document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "11";
           document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "12";
        }

        function levelD()
        {
          //this is where the "fortunes" will 
        }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body onload= "startGame();" background="https://lh5.ggpht.com/w8vlt89U83TIzbDNDRdGBmFh3kS9wJthH3l8awOXRIx-CRSZ8aKtubFip8O7Mz7nABk=h900">
<center><h1><font color ="white" size="30"> Fortune Teller!</font></h1></center>
<center><font size = "27" color ="white"><div id="message">Pick a number!</div></font></center>
<center><table border= "35" bgcolor= "#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td id="s1" class= "Square" onclick="levelA();"></td>
        <td id="s2" class= "Square" onclick="levelA();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="s3" class= "Square" onclick="levelA();"></td>
        <td id="s4" class= "Square" onclick="levelA();"></td>        </tr>

</table></center>
     <center><button type="button" onclick=startGame()> Get New Fortune</button>    </center>
   <center><p><font color ="white"> Created By </font></p> 
  </center>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: use https://jsfiddle.net  to put your POC

Comment: If you create an anonymous StackOverflow account, might I suggest you remove your name from the source code too?

Comment: `<font>`  [that's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) so [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#HTML_versions_timeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First of All :

This Fiddle works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/v7038zsd/1/

## Recommendations :

1.Use anonymous function :

```
 (function(window,document){
     // All your code here

  })(window,document)
```

2.Use JS library that organizes code modularity : .i.e. :jQuery